# Looking for Javascript calendar that will embed in a web page and get data from PHP/MySQL server

Tags: javascript

I've been hunting for a long time for this, but despite my intuition that this would be a common thing, I haven't encountered anything that meets my requirements.

I just need a month calendar that I can display in a web page which will show events. Each event just needs to show the name, and that name will link to another page.

The calendar needs to be large and readable, something in the neighborhood of 600 or 800 pixels wide. I should be able to colour the lines and text and so on with CSS. Should not rely on any image files.

Data needs to be pulled from the server via JSON. I have an existing PHP/MySQL set up on the server side, and I can write the PHP to accept and send the right JSON data. I only need the Javascript side of things.

The reason I have not found anything like this is because the calendars I have found have fallen into two distinct categories:

One are calendars that are build with the intention of having people interface with the calendar and add, share, or edit events. I strictly only need to display (events in my case are added to the database via a different interface). The amount of code overhead for that kind of interaction makes them way too huge and unweildy to edit down to my needs.

The other type of common Javascript calendars are the types used in forms, that are often seen in drop downs, used for picking a single date. These are obviously too small and are in any case too different from what I need to extend to my purposes.

I can edit Javascript, but building an entire Gregorian calendar with all the little mathmatical tricks to account for days and rows and columns in a table representing a month seems like reinventing a very complicated wheel.

Perhaps I am using the wrong search terms or something. Are there any existing code bases available that do what I hope to acheive?

Free and/or open source is of course the ideal, but I will consider purchasing if necessary.

Comment: Calendars are hard. And dull. Nobody writes a calendar widget for fun, so naturally, good ones are hard to find, if they exist at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already know jQuery-based [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) as it falls into your first category, but I still think it's a superb choice. You can disable all the interaction abilities, and it's widely customizable.

It has day, week, and month views, can pull data via Ajax, and displays multiple-events (and multiple-day/week events) beautifully.

There may be a leaner solution out there that does the same thing but I don't know of one.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I believe I did look at this one, and discounted it for being too complicated, but I will keep it in mind if a better option doesn't present itself.

Comment: After working with it a bit more, this will suit my needs after all. Thank you for suggesting it!